# Construct an Arrow DoubleArray from double pointer

Tags: c++, apache-arrow

I have a two-dimensional double array pointer. I can cast it to `u_int8_t`, fetch it to `mutable_data()` of Arrow Pool Buffer, and construct an Arrow DoubleArray. However, when I get value from `Value()`, `raw_values()` of the array, I cannot get correct number. Someone please see my code and help me:

```
double* generateDoubleArray() {
    int totalColumns = 200;
    int totalRows = 200;
    std::random_device r;
    std::default_random_engine e1(r());
    std::normal_distribution<double> nor_dist(-1, 1);

    double *A = static_cast<double *>(malloc(totalColumns * totalRows * sizeof(double *)));
    for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < totalColumns; j++) {
            A[i*totalColumns + j] = sin(nor_dist(e1)) + exp(sin(nor_dist(e1)) + cos(nor_dist(e1)));
        }
    }

    return A;
}
int main()
{
    double* generatedDouble = generateDoubleArray();
    uint8_t *ui_generatedDouble = (uint8_t*)generatedDouble;
    arrow::MemoryPool* pool_;
    pool_ = arrow::default_memory_pool();
    auto data = std::make_shared<arrow::PoolBuffer>(pool_);
    size_t length = 200 * 200;
    const size_t data_nbytes = length * sizeof(double *);

    data->Resize(data_nbytes);
    *data->mutable_data() = *ui_generatedDouble;
    auto out = std::make_shared<arrow::DoubleArray>(data_nbytes, data);

    double test_value = out->Value(0); // The returned value is not correct

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line does not do what you think:

```
*data->mutable_data() = *ui_generatedDouble;
```

It only copies the first byte of data. You want to memcopy the entire buffer:

```
std::memcpy(data->mutable_data(), ui_generatedDouble, data_nbytes);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried your approach, it works.